# Bash script exiting when repeated in double click execution

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

This is my code

```
#!/bin/bash
function boo {

    function goo {
        echo "Please enter name"
            read name;
        echo "Hello $name"

    }

    function xoo {

        echo "Please enter number"
        read numl;
        echo "$numl"
    }

    read -p "`echo $'\n> \n>'`  Name N or Number S`echo $'\n> \n>'`" var
        if [[ $var =~ [nN](es)* ]]
            then    
                goo   
                elif [[ $var =~ [sS](es)* ]]
                then
                xoo
                fi

}
boo
read -p "`echo $'\n> \n>'`  To Repeat press Y`echo $'\n> \n>'`" prompt
if [[ $prompt =~ [yY](es)* ]]
then
boo    
else
echo""
fi
```

Initially I am able to successfully run this script by double clicking but when I tried to repeat it its exiting

```
> 
>  Name N or Number S
> 
>n
Please enter name
john
Hello john

> 
>  To Repeat press Y
> 
>y

> 
>  Name N or Number S
> 
>n
Please enter name
ajay
```

I am able to print hello john but when i enter ajay its exiting. Any idea whats happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the `if…then`. After the first call off `boo` you check the value of `prompt` and `boo` will be started, if `prompt` is `y`. After that, there is no more code to execute and the script exits.

Using this script

```
#!/bin/bash
function boo {
    function goo {
        echo "Please enter name"
        read -r name;
        echo "Hello $name"
    }

    function xoo {
        echo "Please enter number"
        read -r numl;
        echo "$numl"
    }

    read -rep $'\n> \n> Name N or Number S \n> \n> ' var
    if [[ $var =~ [nN](es)* ]]; then    
      goo   
    elif [[ $var =~ [sS](es)* ]]; then
      xoo
    fi
}

while true; do
  boo
  read -rep $'\n> \n> To Repeat press Y \n> \n> ' prompt
  if [[ ! $prompt =~ [yY](es)* ]]; then
    break
  fi
done

exit 0
```

---

*Example*

```
% ./foo

> 
> Name N or Number S 
> 
> N
Please enter name
abc
Hello abc

> 
> To Repeat press Y 
> 
> y

> 
> Name N or Number S 
> 
> N
Please enter name
def
Hello def

> 
> To Repeat press Y 
> 
> y

> 
> Name N or Number S 
> 
> N
Please enter name
jjj
Hello jjj

> 
> To Repeat press Y 
> 
> n
%
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but can you tell me where i made the mistake. why **read -r** , **read -rep** and while loop